# Триггер с составной структурой

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE newsklad
(
  "Name" character varying,
  "Uint" character varying,
  "Count" numeric,
  "CreateTime" timestamp without time zone,
  "Changed" boolean,
  "OneCID" character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "newsklad_Name_CreateTime_key" UNIQUE ("Name", "CreateTime")
)


CREATE TABLE sklad
(
  "Name" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Uint" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Count" numeric,
  "CreateTime" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "Changed" boolean,
  "OneCID" character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "sklad_Name_CreateTime_key" UNIQUE ("Name", "CreateTime")
)

CREATE TABLE "Transfer"
(
  "ID" serial NOT NULL,
  "Date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  "SkladPostav" character varying NOT NULL,
  "NameSklad" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Сomposition" comprositionttransfer[] NOT NULL,
  "Operator" character varying NOT NULL,
  "Total" numeric,
  "UpdateOper" text,
  "Changed" boolean,
  "OneCID" character varying,
  CONSTRAINT transfer_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

И триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transfer_insert_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$
DECLARE
    rec ComprositiontTransfer;


    sqlSelectPrixodPostav varchar;
    sqlSelectPrixodPostav2 varchar;
    sqlInsertPrixodPostav varchar;
    sqlUpdatePrixodPostav varchar;
    count numeric;
    countlen numeric;
    countTovar numeric;
    CreateList timestamp without time zone;
BEGIN 



    sqlSelectPrixodPostav = 'Select count("Count") From ' || NEW."NameSklad" || '  WHERE ("Name" = $1) and ("CreateTime" = $2)'; 
    sqlSelectPrixodPostav2 = 'Select "Count" From ' || NEW."NameSklad" || '  WHERE ("Name" = $1) and ("CreateTime" = $2) ORDER BY "Count" '; 
    sqlUpdatePrixodPostav = 'UPDATE ' || NEW."NameSklad" || ' SET "Count" = $3, "Changed" = true WHERE ("Name" = $1) and ("CreateTime" = $2)';
    sqlInsertPrixodPostav = 'INSERT INTO ' || NEW."NameSklad" || ' ("Name", "Uint", "Count", "CreateTime", "Changed") VALUES ($1,(Select "Units" From "Product" s WHERE (s."Name" = $1)) , $2, $3, true)';
    /*execute sqlInsertPrixodPostav using 'Огурчик',5452;*/
    FOR rec.Name, rec.Count, rec.CreateTime IN SELECT u.Name, u.Count, u.CreateTime FROM  unnest(NEW."Сomposition") u  GROUP BY u.Name, u.Count, u.CreateTime
        LOOP
        execute sqlSelectPrixodPostav into countlen using rec.Name,  CreateList;
        execute sqlSelectPrixodPostav2 into countTovar using rec.Name,  CreateList;
        if countlen = 0 then
            execute sqlInsertPrixodPostav using rec.Name, rec.Count , CreateList;
        else 
            countTovar := countTovar +  rec.Count;
            execute sqlUpdatePrixodPostav using rec.Name, CreateList, countTovar;
        end if;
    END LOOP;

    return NEW;
END;
$TRIGGER$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_transfer_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON "Transfer" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE transfer_insert_trigger_func();
```

Заполняем таблицу значениями

```
INSERT INTO sklad(
            "Name", "Uint", "Count", "CreateTime")
    VALUES ('Мука', 'кг', 40, '2016-10-10 10:10:10');
```

B создаем отчет по транспортировке:

```
INSERT INTO "Transfer"(
             "Date", "SkladPostav", "NameSklad", "Сomposition", "Operator", "Total")
    VALUES ( '2016-10-10 10:10:20', 'sklad', 'newsklad','{"(\"Мука\",''2016-11-03 10:30:25'',1,\"asdasdas\",\" \")"}', 'Коровкина',252);
```

Дак в таблице newsklad появляется только имя и количество, без времени, пишет что NULL.
Никак не могу понять, почему?

Comment: Не вижу, где задается значение для переменной CreateList. Впрочем, с синтаксисом postgreSQL не знаком, возможно, просто не знаю какой-то тонкости.

Comment: Я конечно не буду матерится, так как нельзя, но видимо сильно тяжелый день был,... Спасибо братан.